# Write to text file using ArrayList

Tags: java

The program is basically about reading from a text file, storing the current data into an ArrayList, then writing data (from user input) into the same text file. Kindly let me know where I am going wrong in this sub-part? The data inside the text file is as follows:

> abc t1 1900
>
> xyz t2 1700

The compiler is showing an error at the line `output.format("%s%s%s%n",`

```
public class justTesting {
    private Scanner input;
    private Formatter output;
    private ArrayList<Student> tk = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        justTesting app = new justTesting();

        app.create();
        app.writeToFile();
    }

    public void create() {
        Text entry = new Text();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("%s\n", "Please enter your name, ID, and year: ");

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            try {
                entry.setName(input.next());
                entry.setTelNumber(input.next());
                entry.setDOB(input.next());

                for (int i = 0; i < tk.size(); i++) {
                    output.format("%s%s%s%n", tk.get(i).getName(), tk.get(i)
                            .getTelNumber(), tk.get(i).getDOB());
                }

            } catch (FormatterClosedException fce) {
                System.err.println("Error writing to file.");
                return;
            } catch (NoSuchElementException nsee) {
                System.err.println("Invalid input. Try again: ");
                input.nextLine();
            }
            System.out.printf("%s\n", "Please enter your name, ID, and year: ");
        }
    }

    public void writeToFile() {
        try {
            output = new Formatter("testing.txt");
        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            System.err
                    .println("You do not have write access permission to this file.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.err.println("Error opening or creating file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What was `output` declared as?  Is it even declared/instantiated?  I can't see that with this snippet of code.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: You're stating 4 references in the format `%s%s%s%n` and you only pass 3.

Comment: output is declared as `private Formatter output` and the error says `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @m0skit0 The `%n` is for carriage return in a text file. It works like `/r/n`

Comment: Show the code in which you actually instantiate this `Formatter` object.  It may be that you're trying to use it before you declare a new instance of it.  Also, `tk` is kinda floating out there too; show us how you've created/instantiated that too, if you don't mind.

Comment: @Makoto I don't mind but there's no use. That is the only place where I'm using the variable `output`

Comment: It's actually *very* important.  `NullPointerException`s occur when you try to dereference a null object.  If the objects you're using aren't instantiated, then you'll run into this issue a lot.  Also, if you're only using `output` here, then it doesn't serve a very useful purpose as a global variable.

Comment: @Makoto Alright. Added the code where declaration takes place. I'll be using `output` in another method later on.

Comment: Added instantiation at `output = new Formatter("testing.txt");`

Comment: But now you can't call create() before writeToFile(), or else output is still null. Also, the code as is creates a new Formatter every time you call writeToFile(). Is there any reason why we can't instantiate it elsewhere? That way you don't have this dependency, and you won't create a new Formatter every time.

Comment: @Dennis Meng Yes. I need to call `create()` before `writeToFile()`. Still debugging.

Comment: I think I need to append to file. Still working on the code. Will let you all know how it goes. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed %n and it worked. Thanks everyone.